# How to record 2 dimensional FFT data in a Prometheus/Micrometer metric?

Tags: kotlin, histogram, prometheus, fft, micrometer

I want to use a few Android phones as a remote audio frequency detectors, and I need to collect the data from a few different phones and analyse them centrally using Prometheus/Grafana.

I've got an Android app (using [Noise](https://github.com/paramsen/noise)) that successfully records audio, and analyses it (using [Kiss FFT](https://github.com/mborgerding/kissfft)) to compute the magnitude of each frequency.

Noise returns the FFT as a `FloatArray`, and the Android app uses that to visualise the audio frequencies as a heat-map and a histogram.

```kotlin
import android.media.AudioRecord
import com.paramsen.noise.Noise
import com.paramsen.noise.sample.R
import com.paramsen.noise.sample.source.AudioSource

/** Subscribe to microphone updates */
private fun start(recorder: AudioRecord) {

  val src = AudioSource(recorder).stream()
  val noise = Noise.real(SAMPLE_SIZE)

  //FFT Views
  disposable.add(src.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .map { 
      // compute the FFT
      noise.fft(it, FloatArray(SAMPLE_SIZE + 2)) 
    }
    .subscribe({ fft: FloatArray ->
      // forward the FFT data to the visualisers
      fftHeatMapView.onFFT(fft)
      fftBandView.onFFT(fft)
    }, { e -> Log.e(TAG, e.message ?: "null") })
  )
}

const val RATE_HZ = 44100
const val SAMPLE_SIZE = 4096
```

The FFT data is rendered as expected (more or less - I think the windowing function needs tweaking).

[image: 'Noise' Android app showing FFT spectrogram and histogram]

The next step is to try and forward the FFT data to Prometheus. I created a new handler for the FFT data, and created a Prometheus histogram metric.

```kotlin
object FFTMetrics : FFTView {

  private val registry = PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT)

  private val fftDist = DistributionSummary
    .builder("fft.dist")
    .description("FFT distribution")
    .baseUnit("hertz")
    //.scale(100.0)
    .register(registry)

  override fun onFFT(fft: FloatArray) {
    // TODO
  }
}
```

However, the only option I have available is to record a single reading, which in this instance is not correct. Each float value of the FFT array represents the *magnitude* of the recorded frequency. The array is 2 dimensional, where the index represents the hertz, while the Micrometer metric only allows for recording a 1 dimensional value.

```kotlin
override fun onFFT(fft: FloatArray) {
  fft.forEach { magnitude: Float ->
    // this is incorrect:
    summary.record(magnitude.toDouble())
  }
}
```

What I want to do instead is increase a single bucket multiple times

```kotlin
override fun onFFT(fft: FloatArray) {
  fft.forEachIndexed { i: Int, magnitude: Float ->
    val hz = computeHertzForBin(i)
    // I want to record multiple readings per bin:
    summary.record(hz, magnitude)
  }
}
```

I have tried implementing an equivalent with a for-loop, but it is slow and unwieldy, and requires converting between numeric types unnecessarily.

```kotlin
override fun onFFT(fft: FloatArray) {
  fft.forEachIndexed { i, magnitude ->
    val hz = computeHertzForBin(i)
    (0..magnitude.toLong()).forEach { j ->
      summary.record(hz.toDouble())
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of recording 2 dimensional data in Micrometer or Prometheus?

##### Versions

I'm using

- Kotlin 1.6.21
- Android 7.3.1
- Micrometer 1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Answering directly to your question, Prometheus does not accept multidimensional values. To accomplish this, you should use labels. In your example, seems to me that Hz would be a label, and magnitude would be its value. For instance, supposing your metric is called `signal_magnitude`, I think you are proposing:

`signal_magnitude = 10KHz, 10.11`

(meaning a magnitude of 10.11 for the frequency 10KHz - all arbitrary numbers I invented to compose the example)

Since the set of frequencies is known and finite, it is suitable to be a label:

`signal_magnitude{frequency=100000} = 10.11`

In this case, your exporter would present Prometheus a set of metrics like:

```
signal_magnitude{frequency=10000} = 10.11
signal_magnitude{frequency=20000} = 5.0
signal_magnitude{frequency=30000} = 3.76
signal_magnitude{frequency=40000} = 18.27
signal_magnitude{frequency=50000} = 8.943
```

In order to analyze this, one can use the `frequency` label as a dimension to the heatmap chart.

Notice that it is important to consider how many different values a label can assume, this will express the cardinality of your database. Since each different combination of metric name and label set increases the cardinality. That is why label values shall be finite.

Now, following other thoughts, is Prometheus the right tool for your application?

Since Prometheus scrapes the metric you present to it every N seconds, if you update the metric values more than once in less than N seconds, you will lose data points. Even if you are willing to push metrics via Pushgateway, they will be overwritten there and scraped once by Prometheus server.

Also, Prometheus doesn't allow for back-filling, meaning if your are post processing this audio files you cannot specify data points in the past. The timestamp of a datapoint is given by the scrape time of Prometheus server.

If you need "every single data point in time" to be in the database and knowing the timing (scrape interval) is controlled by Prometheus server (not your app) and also that missed scrapes means loss of data point, I would consider another time series database for this task. Maybe InfluxDB would be more appropriate for this scenario.

Comment: I agree that Prometheus might not be the best tool, but it should be suitable for this sort of data. InfluxDB sounds interesting though, I'll take a look.

Comment: The custom label implementation you propose sounds like the existing DistributionSummary metric type, which I believe also solves the problem of 'missing' data as I think it aggregates data until it is scraped. The problem, however, seems to be that only 'increment' function that DistributionSummary has only allows incrementing a specific bucket by 1, not by an arbitrary amount. I don't really want to re-implement DistributionSummary just for that functionality...

Comment: I am not sure it solve the missing data issue. If you are going to use pushgateway for this task you are certainly tied to a single value per scrape and any update between scrapes are lost. I am pretty sure that all libraries for prometheus metrics works the same, if you present a metric twice on the http requet from prometheus, I don't know what it does, and the timestamp for those will be the same. (the prometheus time, not collected time)